# Installing PortAudio for use with Cygwin on Windows 7

Tags: c, windows, gcc, cygwin, portaudio

I'm trying to get PortAudio to work on my computer. I've been using Cygwin and gcc to make applications in C, but I'm completely clueless as to how I might go about getting PortAudio to compile and work on my system.

I've found info on PortAudio's website for getting it to work with Microsoft Visual Studio, but I'm not using that IDE (or any for that matter. Just been working in Notepad++ and running things from the command line).

If anyone has any info for how I might get this to work, or where I might look for an answer, it would be much appreciated!
Thanks!
-Justin

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to follow the [PortAudio instructions for Linux](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_linux.html).

As it says in the instructions, "You might need to use yum, or some other package manager, instead of apt-get on your machine". In the case of Cygwin, that probably means using the Cygwin setup.exe program.